# Locking orientation in unity3d game for ASUS (windows) tablet through code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can i lock orientation for unity 3d game through code? This is for Asus tablet.

Answer (score 1):

You do this through the Editor in Player Settings.

```
Player Settings -> Resolution and Presentation -> Resolution: Default Orientation
```

Edit: Here is a picture.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can manually set the orientation like so:

```
iPhoneSettings.screenOrientation = iPhoneScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```

iPhoneSettings should apply to all portable devices, not just iOS.  For some reason the screenOrientation variable isn't defined in the documentation and it doesn't show up in MonoDevelop's intellisense.